# How to use loop variable inside pandas df.query()

Tags: python, pandas

How do I fix the following `df.query` line to stop getting the error msg: `name 'z' is not defined.`

I have data in 3 columns and wanna plot 3D polygons. I run a loop to pair up (X, Y), in which I try to use the loop variable, `z`, to screen one column:

```
zs = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
for z in zs:
    ys = df.query('column1==z')['Column2']
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use format strings:

```
zs = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
for z in zs:
    ys = df.query(f'column1=={z}')['Column2']
    verts.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
```

Answer (score 4):

From your code, you may passe the value of `z`, not the sting `"z"`, do thta with a formatted string for example or just concat the elements

```
ys = df.query(f'column1=={z}')['Column2']
ys = df.query('column1==' + str(z))['Column2']
```

But the slicing syntax is a bit more easy to use

```
ys = df[df.column1 == z]['Column2']
```