# Using variable within the 'query' method of pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I wanted to use external variable with the `query` method in a `pandas dataframe`. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'], 'col2' : [2,3,4], 'col3' : [10,11,12]})

ii = 'BB'

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([[df1.query("col1 == @ii").reset_index(drop = True).iloc[0, 1] * jj for jj in range(0,3)], 
                [df1.query("col1 == @ii").reset_index(drop = True).iloc[0, 2] + jj for jj in range(0,3)]]).T for ii in df1['col1'].values], axis = 1)
```

The result looks strange to me. I used a variable `ii` within `query` method which supposed to change based on different values of `col1`. But it appears to take only the value `ii = 'BB'` which is defined externally.

Is there any explanation to this behavior? How can I change the value of `ii` within `query` method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use loop variable inside pandas df.query()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828539/how-to-use-loop-variable-inside-pandas-df-query)

Comment: Yes it is. But I am still not cleat why `@ii ` is not working in this case